# Spring Cassandra repository - how to search with empty clustering key

Tags: java, database, spring, cassandra, repository

I have a question on using spring cassandra repository for searching query. I have a table with one partition key and one clustering key together as composite primary key. So in the mapping layer, I create a class for PrimanyKey using @PrimaryKeyClass and @PrimaryKeyColumn, then use @PrimaryKey for the mapping class

the table is created with the following cql

```
CREATE TABLE user_mobile (phonenum text,memberid uuid,gender text,nickname text,photo timeuuid,PRIMARY KEY (phonenum, memberid))
```

I create a class called PK_UserMobile to act as primary key class

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
  public class PK_UserMobile implements Serializable {
  @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
  private String phoneNum;
  @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
  private UUID memberId;
......
}
```

and my mapping class is something like this

```
@Table("user_mobile")
public class UserMobile extends BaseDto {

 @PrimaryKey
 private PK_UserMobile pk;

........
}
```

and it is fine to run cql like "select * from user_mobile where phonenum = 'xxxxxxxxx' ;". So I guess it is fine for search this table with partition key only. When I try to search using spring cassandra repository, seems it require me to provide both phonenum's and memberid's value for searching usage. the following exception is thrown if I only set up the value for phonenum.

```
"com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid null value in condition for column memberid. "
```

So I wanna know if any special null object should I pass in the clustering key as a searching condition? or should I do it in any other way? Thank you.

Comment: did you find any sollution on this? I am facing the same problem. thanks in advance

Comment: Please add your repository interface to the question. It should be `extends CrudRepository<UserMobile, PK_UserMobile>` with a custom method `List<UserMobile> findByPkPhoneNum(String phoneNum);` to be mapped to the desired query.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because of that you use the standard CRUD repository function `findById`. To solve the problem, declare a query method on your repository with the following pattern:

> findBy{key class name}{property of the key class}

in your case your query method is:

```
List<UserMobile> findByPK_UserMobilePhoneNum(String phoneNum);
```

Comment: What will be the implementation for `findByPK_UserMobilePhoneNum()` ? Just adding this method in the Repository class did not work.

Comment: @User_Targaryen you do not need to implement anything, spring will generate corresponding query. Check https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods  for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way to accomplish this.

No need for a separate `PrimaryKeyClass`

```
@Table("user_mobile")
public class UserMobile extends BaseDto {
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String phoneNum;
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    private UUID memberId;
    ........
}
```

Now, define the repository using `MapIdCassandraRepository`

```
@Repository
public interface UserMobileRepository extends MapIdCassandraRepository<UserMobile> {
    @Query("SELECT * from user_mobile where phoneNum=?0")
    List<UserMobile> findByPhoneNum(String phoneNum);
}
```

This will work!